# How to create a link back to parent list?

Tags: laravel-nova

In Laravel Nova, when in a typical details view (e.g. a record), is it possible to have a convenient explicit link back to the parent list view (e.g. top-level of a Nova resource)?

This is for UX convenience.

**Example:**

1. Given Nova Resource "My Books", it shows a list of "Books".
2. I click a "Book" to view-or-edit.
3. **PROBLEM:** I decide to return to parent list "My Books", but AFAICT there's no way to do this except by using my browser native
   back-button

**Browser-native "Back" is alien to me**
I'm using various single-page-applications all day long. I do not have an instinct to hit browser-"Back" (or Backspace) as I feel like it exits me out of the session.

IMHO within this entire Nova experience, everything is done with clicking explicit things... so, for a simple "Back" event (which you'd use 100's of times if managing records) why would it be handled any differently? My cursor is right there in the middle of the screen ready for a quick swipe-click.

[image]

Comment: Consider https://github.com/chris-ware/nova-breadcrumbs perhaps.

Comment: Ahhh nice one! thx